# C++ concept that a type is same_as any one of several types?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I would like to define a concept that indicates a type is one of several supported types.  I can do this by repeatedly listing the types with `std::same_as<T, U>`:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
concept IsMySupportedType = std::same_as<T, int32_t> || std::same_as<T, int64_t> || std::same_as<T, float> || std::same_as<T, double>;
```

Is there a more concise way to write this without repeating the `std::same_as` concept?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be done using a variadic helper concept (taken from the cppreference for [`std::same_as`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/same_as)):

```cpp
template <typename T, typename... U>
concept IsAnyOf = (std::same_as<T, U> || ...);
```

This can be used to define the desired concept as follows:

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept IsMySupportedType = IsAnyOf<T, std::int32_t, std::int64_t, float, double>;
```

Note that the initial `T` on the right-hand side is important.

The resulting concept can be used as expected:

```cpp
static_assert(IsMySupportedType<float>);
static_assert(!IsMySupportedType<std::int8_t>);
```

Compiling example:  https://godbolt.org/z/6dE9r1EY6

Comment: The initial `T` is automatically added only when a concept name or concept template-id is used as a constraining type for a declaration, as in `void f(IsAnyOf<char, float, double> value);` or `template <IsAnyOf<char, float, double> T>`

Comment: "*In my mind, the initial T on the right-hand side should be implicit and not required*" Um... why? You're not using it on one of the places where a type is already present (such as `->` notation in a `requires` expression).

Comment: @aschepler, Nicol Bolas, thanks for clarifying that this is not the right context for implicit use of the type parameter.

Comment: I guess there's also `IsAnyOf<char, float, double> auto var = 0.0;`, where it's not exactly standing in place of a type but is related to a declaration.

Comment: This is nice… but can you unpack the parameter pack from e.g. `std::variant<>` (or any generic template type that takes a parameter pack)?

Answer (score 5):

I would use [`std::disjunction`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction) which has the upside that it is short-circuiting:
*"if there is a template type argument `Bi` with `bool(Bi::value) != false`, then instantiating `disjunction<B1, ..., BN>::value` does not require the instantiation of `Bj::value` for `j > i`"*

```
template <class T, class... U>
concept any_of = std::disjunction_v<std::is_same<T, U>...>;

template <class T>
concept IsMySupportedType = any_of<T, std::int32_t, std::int64_t, float, double>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8sbq3K6hP)

Comment: I understand the general benefit of `std::disjunction`, but is there a use where it would make a difference here? `std::is_same<T, U>::value` isn't going to fail to instantiate even if `T` or `U` is incomplete.

Comment: Can the concepts machinery "look inside" `std::disjunction_v<...>` for purposes of partial ordering of constraints?  That would be my concern about `std::disjunction_v`.

Comment: @aschepler It's not that it would fail but that it wouldn't even instantiate the rest of the `is_same`s if a match is found.

Comment: @NicholasM I'm not sure I understand. It'll instantiate the `is_same`s in the order you've supplied the parameters `U...` but it won't instantiate more `is_same`s than needed.

Comment: Right, so if I have my own trait `is_special` where the `value` member involves `T&`, I can do `std::disjunction_v<std::is_reference<T>, is_special<T>>`, and it will avoid instantiating `is_special` with a reference type. `std::is_same` and `std::same_as` don't have any issues like that, so does using `disjunction_v` make a difference?

Comment: The point about partial ordering of constraints is a good one: Using the fold expression, `IsAnyOf<T, int, char, double>` subsumes `IsAnyOf<T, double, int>`. Using `disjunction_v`, `any_of<T, int, char, double>` does not subsume `any_of<T, double, int>`, so overloading on those constraints would become ambiguous.

Comment: @aschepler The compiled code will probably be just as effective but instantiating a lot of `is_same`s (that aren't needed) can increase compilation time. It's just not necessary to instantiate them so I'd prefer to skip that.  I'm sorry, but I don't understand the subsuming bit (not a native English speaker). Can you put something on godbolt that shows the problem?

Comment: Hmm, clang and gcc don't order the fold expression either. Maybe I'm wrong to expect that to work, but that's definitely a language-lawyer investigation.

Comment: @aschepler When you say _"order the fold expression"_, what does that mean? The fold expression will _unfold_ to `std::same_as<T, U1> || std::same_as<T, U2> || ... || std::same_as<T, Ux>`, that is, the same expression OP started out with in the question.

Comment: @TedLyngmo But apparently (and I think I see why from the Standard) that unfolding doesn't happen before partial ordering of constraints: https://godbolt.org/z/4n6EWdf8e

Comment: @aschepler I'm reading up on [constraint normalization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Constraint_normalization). Tricky :-)

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't think so. The normalized constraint of `(E)` is the same as the normalized constraint of `E`. I think the issue is the associated constraint expression is the fold expression, and not its subexpressions after the pack is substituted.

Comment: @Deduplicator Constraint normalization looks inside parentheses.

Comment: aschepler & Deduplicator - lovely discussion, seriously! Can you bring it into an answer? I wrote my answer thinking that there are only upsides to preventing instantiations of the "unfolded" template - but then... _"looks inside"_ makes me not so sure. Are there concrete examples of when using a fold expression has any benefit over `disjunction` (when applicable)? Am I wrong in assuming that the short-circuiting `disjunction` also helps when used in `concepts`?